# Cisco IOS command show users

Tags: cisco, switch, router

I'm using this cisco IOS command "show users" to check if there's more than one session active and the session's IP address, however I've noticed that on certain devices, this command hangs before displaying the IP address of the user for like 1 minute.

Does anyone know what could be causing this delay?.

I've checked for cpu and memory usage, and that doesn't seem to be the cause, also checked on different ios versions.

Comment: Try disabling domain lookup---  no ip domain-lookup

Comment: @RonTrunk maybe add this as an answer so this question doesn't remain "unanswered" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The apparent "hanging" is caused by the delay in doing name resolution (DNS) lookups.  If you don't have name resolution available, you can disable the lookup with the command

```
no ip domain-lookup
```

Comment: the `wide` option (as in `show users wide`) after the commend solved it for me.